# what is the method(way) to use data of html in component of angular 2?

Tags: html, angular, components

in angular 2 there is a button that I want when click on it a div appear.

```
<button class="dokme" type="button" (click)="onSelect(signUp)" >Register</button>
<div *ngIf="selectedBtn">
  <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

and I couldn't complete my component, because I don't know how I should write it:

```
onSelect():void{
  this.selectedBtn=...(?)}
```

Actually I know it can be similat to *"Hide the empty detail with ngIf"* in angular tutorial [Hide the empty detail with ngIf](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2), but the problem is I can't change that code to what I want. Because in that example there is hero and I don't know what should I replace it.
please help me in the simplest way it would be your kind.

Comment: `this.selectedBtn = true`? I don't really get your issue :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you pas into `(click)` will be executed when you click on the button.

If the expression you pass into `*ngIf` is `true`, the content inside the element will be present on the page. Otherwise, it will not.

So, what you ned to do is to change the value of `selectedBtn` when `(click)` event happens.

#### Template

```
<button class="dokme" type="button" (click)="onSelect()" >Register</button>
<div *ngIf="selectedBtn">
  <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

#### Component

```
onSelect() {
  this.selectedBtn = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the variable to `true`

```
onSelect() {
  this.selectedBtn = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngIf` works in a simmilar way that `if` statement in other programming languages so it checks for condition and if it is `true` (or if a function called in condition returns `true`). In this case, your `ngIf` is linked to component variable `selectedBtn` so only what you need to do is set it to `true`:

```
this.selectedBtn = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

More easily, you can achieve the sane goal without creating new function in your controller.

```
<button class="dokme" type="button" (click)="selectedBtn=true" >Register</button>
<div *ngIf="selectedBtn">
  <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

Or if you want the button to toggle :

```
<button class="dokme" type="button" (click)="selectedBtn=!selectedBtn" >Register</button>
<div *ngIf="selectedBtn">
  <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a discouraged approach, though. Try not to have any logic in your templates.